# Function assignments of an interface of a structure pointer with a structure show different values

Tags: go, methods, struct, interface

I'm a bit confused with the next part of the code:

```
type Tiger struct {
    weight int
}

func (t Tiger) Weight() int {
    return t.weight
}

type AsianTiger struct {
    Tiger
}

type Tigers interface {
    Weight() int
}

func main() {
    t := &AsianTiger{Tiger{3}}

    var i Tigers = t

    f := t.Weight
    g := i.Weight

    t.weight = 7

    fmt.Println(f(), g()) // result is: 3 7 | expected 7 7

    z := t
    x := i

    t.weight = 8

    fmt.Println(z.Weight(), x.Weight()) // result is: 8 8

}
```

Could someone help me please to understand what is happening with `f := t.Weight` and `g := i.Weight` why did they show different results when I expected similarity, and what is happening under the hood?

Comment: 1. Rule: Never write such code. 2. Remeber that it is totally impossible to simulate inheritance.

Comment: Hello, it is not really helpful, I'm not trying to make anything, it just a piece of the code from the internet which I could not understand, I tried to debug it and read docs, but didn't find an 100% answer, so I thought maybe someone could explain me on stackoveflow.

Answer (score 5):

The source of the problem / confusion lies in these lines:

```
f := t.Weight
g := i.Weight
```

These are [method values](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values). **A method value saves the receiver in the result function value!** And your `Tiger.Weight()` method has value receiver (not pointer receiver):

```
func (t Tiger) Weight() int {
    return t.weight
}
```

This means that `t.Weight` will save the receiver `t`, which is a `Tiger` struct, and along with it the current `weight=3` field. (Note: it's true that in `f:= t.Weight` `t` is an `*AsianTiger` value, but `t.Weight` is a promoted method from the embedded `Tiger` type, so `t.Weight` effectively means / denotes the `AsianTiger.Tiger.Weight()` method whose receiver is a `Tiger` struct value.)

The method value `i.Weight` on the other hand is a method of `Tigers`, the interface, and the concrete value wrapped in it is of type `*AsianTiger`, a pointer. So the pointer value will be saved.

Next you change the weight:

```
t.weight = 7
```

This will not effect `f`, because the `Tiger` struct value (the receiver) is saved, it's a copy. This will however effect `g`, because the saved receiver there is `Tigers` which holds `*AsianTiger`, and you change the pointed value (not the pointer).

You can see if you add another line:

```
fmt.Println(f(), g())               // result is: 3 7 | expected 7 7
fmt.Println(t.Weight(), i.Weight()) // result is: 7 7
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/s-DgvXmciIG)):

```
3 7
7 7
```

The second line prints `7 7` because not a saved receiver value is used, but the actual value of `t` (and `i` which points to `t`).

The remaining of your code:

```
z := t
x := i

t.weight = 8

fmt.Println(z.Weight(), x.Weight()) // result is: 8 8
```

Here `z` and `x` are not method values. `z` is a copy of `t` which is a pointer, and `x` is a copy of `i`, an interface value which wraps a pointer. And you change the pointed value (a field of a field of the pointed value). And last you call the methods of `z` and `x`, no saved receiver takes place, receivers are evaluated after the change.

Comment: Thank you! It is a great explanation, now everything is clear!